# Как сделать прокрутку вверх вниз, ScrollView и HorizontalView даю прокрутку только вправо, влево, вверх , вниз.

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализуется прокрутка "плиточный карты" во всех направлениях, то есть если я тапнул  и свайпнул вверх влево, то карта прокрутилась вниз влево, может направление куда гуглить подскажите

Comment: Лично я много лет уже гуглю такую штуку но так и не нагуглил. Сложилось впечатление что её не существует в готовом виде и в реализации оно так сложно, что никто и не берётся. Правда, @Flippy , вроде, делал что-то такое, но надо у него спрашивать что из этого в итоге вышло)

Comment: Есть такое решение: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6716638